# How can I control the width of this Amazon Affiliates javascript snippet?

Tags: javascript, css

I have an affiliate widget from Amazon.  The widget is a medium rectangle with a width of 300px.  The problem is that the WordPress sidebar I need it to fit into is 280px.

I only have the code Amazon gave me.  But is there a way to manipulate the code of javascript given to me to fit it into my sidebar?

Here is the code:

```
<SCRIPT charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript" src="http://ws-na.amazon-adsystem.com/widgets
/q?rt=tf_mfw&ServiceVersion=20070822&MarketPlace=US&ID=V20070822%2FUS%2Fochl-
20%2F8001%2Feba28422-9df9-42be-99e2-ff04cbbb824b"> </SCRIPT> <NOSCRIPT><A HREF="http://ws-
na.amazon-adsystem.com/widgets/q?rt=tf_mfw&ServiceVersion=20070822&MarketPlace=US&
ID=V20070822%2FUS%2Fochl-20%2F8001%2Feba28422-9df9-42be-99e2-ff04cbbb824b& 
Operation=NoScript">Amazon.com Widgets</A></NOSCRIPT>
```

Any guidance in this regard would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may [try this modified one](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/T7tAz/) ([original](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/T7tAz/1/))

```
#amazon_widget_US_8001_0, #amzn_wdgt_t_8001_0{
    width:280px !important;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#wdgt_brdr{
    overflow:hidden;
    height: 200px !important;
}
```

Add these in your `css` file.

Comment: Thank you for your response, Sheikh!  And thank you for taking the time to construct the fiddles -- they help me learn, just tinkering with them.  I believe with a few tweaks, that should do the trick.  Thanks again!